# ARM LPC1751 pins configured as  I/O

Tags: arm, pins, io

I'm new to microcontroller programming. How can i configure one pin for input and another for output. If I am not wrong this could be done with GPIO registers that control device pins that are not connected to peripheral functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find the complete information in the [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC1759_58_56_54_52_51.pdf) you'll have to look at the [LPC17xx family user manual](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10360.pdf). We're interested in Chapter 9: "LPC17xx General Purpose Input/Output (GPIO)". There you can read that FIODIR is the

> Fast GPIO Port Direction control register. This register individually controls the direction of each port pin.

The direction for each I/O port/pin is controlled by FIO0DIR through FIO4DIR. [Page 132](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10360.pdf#page=132) gives you the corresponding addresses.

*If you don't know how to start looking in these rather long documents, use the "find" function in Acrobat Reader (CTRL-F) and look for "Direction".*

Comment: You may also need to read chapter 8 "Pin connect block".

Comment: thx a lot ... And one more question : where i can get some sample code with arm cortex m3 programming ??

Comment: The corresponding CMSIS library has many demos, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626102/arm-lpc1751-pins-configured-as-i-o/7627617#7627617

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [User Manual](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/pdf/user.manual.lpc17xx.pdf), it seems you would use the FIODIR register mentioned on pages 122-123.
There will be other things that affect the pins like the peripheral settings and Pin Function Select (see p104) so be sure to read the manual thoroughly.